# Libreoffice impress presentation, draw and base not available

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, libreoffice

I'm new in the world of Linux and I have a problem. I installed xubuntu 16.04 and I noticed that the preinstalled Libreoffice was not complete (impress presentation, draw drawing and base database not available) so I upgraded to the newest version with

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa && sudo apt update

sudo apt dist-upgrade && sudo apt install libreoffice-gtk2 libreoffice-gnome
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOlfm.png)

...the upgrade worked but it didn't install the missing programs... How can I install the full suite? Do I have to uninstall and reinstall libreoffice? Thank you

Comment: `sudo apt install libreoffice` ("libreoffice" is a meta-package that install all the additional parts of the office suite; optional extras aren't installed and must be explicitly installed if required). Before doing this remove the PPA and uninstall both packages.

Comment: @CelticWarrior That looks like the beginnings of a good answer to me.

Comment: @ElderGeek I prefer yours :-) I'll upvote it asap (daily limit reached).

Comment: @CelticWarrior expanded answer to cover purging the PPA :-)

Comment: @ElderGeek Nice, already upvoted.

Answer (score 6):

For those of you who haven't resorted to the PPA and just want to install the missing pieces, Open Software Center, type libreoffice in the search box and select the missing components and install them. In my case, base is the only one I don't have installed. Example below:

[image]

If you've already unnecessarily installed the PPA you can revert to the distribution version vis the use of `ppa-purge`

```
ppa-purge provides a bash shell script capable of automatically down‐
       grading all packages in a given PPA back to the ubuntu versions.

       You  have  to  run it using root privileges
```

For further details in it's use please see the man page with the command

`man ppa-purge`

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely, you will have to install Draw in 16.04 > as well, as it is not included by default/OS install. I personally can't stand the software center, it's a dog, like the discontinued Ubuntu Software Center, and don't like the command line, so I would recommend using it for one thing: install 
Synaptic, take a little time to learn to use it, and add what you need there.

It is MUCH easier and faster, you get extra information about what is available, what is installed, version numbers, etc. You can add PPA's and downloaded package files ( .deb ) so you don't have to use a tool like Gdebi, and get all confused running 3 or more package managers on the system (you can only run them one at a time anyway) or blindly installing stuff from command line that you've copied off the web.  It also shows dependencies, suggested  and recommended extras (either or both of which you can set to install automatically, or skip installing) and often, alternatives if you search correctly. 
Great old tool that works!